# Zookeeper data and Znode

Tags: bigdata, apache-zookeeper

I am a beginner in Zookeeper. Would like to know what data means while using create or set command. Zookeeper doesnot store data. Then what is this "data"? Also, znodes are created automatically or should we create it manually in using cli commands?

Comment: ‘Zookeeper doesnot store data’，what do you mean by that.

Comment: I meant that is unlike any database

Comment: yes, unlike other database, zk have to load all data into memory. but zk actually stores data.

Comment: Are these two different questions? Please create separate SO questions. ZooKeeper actually stores data, but it is not meant to be a database. Database usually get larger and larger while new data is created in a system. ZooKeeper works best when it only stores a small amount of data that doesn't grow in time. Basically only data that is used to synchronize a distributed system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZooKeeper *does* store data. When you create a node, you can set this data. You can update the data using setData. It's just an array of bytes. It's up to you to define what it actually is.

However, ZooKeeper is not meant to be a database. Databases usually get larger and larger while a system is used. ZooKeeper works best when it only stores a small amount of data that doesn't grow in time. Basically only data that is used to synchronize a distributed system.

It's up to you how and when you create zNodes. It's certainly easier to deploy when you create them automatically. Usually you have multiple clients. If all of them try to create the same nodes, they will run into conflicts. Make sure to handle this.